# Number of 6-digit pins with no consecutive number nor repeated digit

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

**Synopsis:**

The following question has been asked on a different stackexchange :

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/219197/can-having-certain-restrictions-rules-make-passcodes-less-secure/219203#219203

I provided an answer by computing all the possible values in the subset.
I am now wondering how this result can be found mathematically.

---

**Question:**

Consider a pin [image]

How many pins can be chosen assuming the following rules:

- The pin can not contains 2 consecutive numbers (ie: 112589 not ok, 131313 ok)
- The pin does not contains 2 sequential numbers (ie: 124821 not ok, 142536 ok)
- 9 is sequentially followed by 0

**Partial Answer**

The number of pins verifying the first rule is $10 * 9^5 = 590490$ , the first digit can be whatever, the following digits are chosen from a set of 9 digit (10 except the previous one)

The same number of pins verifies the second rule.

Now, I suppose that the solution is based on the sum of the number of pins verifying the first rule and the number of pins verifying the second rule, **minus the number of the pins that verify both the rules**.

How can the latest subset be defined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just consider both rules simultaneously. For each digit, there are exactly 2 digits which cannot be followed right after: itself and the sequential digit (as $9$ has $0$ as its sequential digit). Since there are only $8$ choices from the second digit onwards, we can thus compute the total number of such pins by $10(8^5)$.

Comment: You're right I went in the wrong direction... Thanks !

Comment: I had to wait a 10 minutes countdown before accepting an answer... This is now done